# Adding Member Changes Upon Saving

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloud, google-cloud-iam

Well I thought I had resolved the issues I had with the owner of a Project in Cloud Storage.

I was able to add my main email as owner and was able to access IAM ... and the 3rd party backup program worked.

Then I had the not so bright idea to remove the other owner ... now backup will not work because it was set to use the deleted owner for access (which is still a surprise to me).

So I went in to the IAM and added the owner back with the same email, quickbooksrus@gmail.com ...
However even though the email is correct when I save, it changes to quickbooks.rus@gmail.com in the permissions list, and because of this I never get the activation email ...

Why does this keep changing ? Because I deleted it in the first place ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out, but it was simply the old email that I never used had a typo in it and was misspelled ... didn't notice it ...

No issues now ... Thank you to the Google Billing Support ...